# Change list of string based dates into one particular format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a list of string that represent dates.

```
input_list = ['18 March 2000', '10-09-2020', '10 JAN 2021', '10/05/2021', '15 FEBRUARY 1990']
```

I wish to change all the formats into ***DD MMM YYYY (10 JAN 2021)***

```
expected_list = ['18 MAR 2000', '10 SEP 2020', '10 JAN 2021', '10 MAY 2021', '15 FEB 1990']
```

Since none of the date strings are of 1 format, datetime.strftime has failed to first convert them into a particular format.

Could anyone suggest a solution to this problem if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-Pandas approach is to use [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse)

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
input_list = ['18 March 2000', '10-09-2020', '10 JAN 2021', '10/05/2021', '15 FEBRUARY 1990']
output = [parse(t).strftime("%d %b %Y").upper() for t in input_list]
print(output)

>>> ['18 MAR 2000', '09 OCT 2020', '10 JAN 2021', '05 OCT 2021', '15 FEB 1990']
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone suggests a better solution, here's one based on Pandas. It converts the list to a DatetimeIndex (that's where the "magic" happens), prints in the required format, and converts back to a list.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DatetimeIndex(input_list).strftime("%d %b %Y").str.upper().tolist()
#['18 MAR 2000', '09 OCT 2020', '10 JAN 2021', '05 OCT 2021', '15 FEB 1990']
```